# Why are unary operators more efficient than standard JavaScript function call?

Tags: javascript, unary-operator

I'm reading the book "JavaScript Notes For Professionals" (free download from this website: https://books.goalkicker.com/JavaScriptBook/). At [chapter 40, page 251: Unary Operators] it says:

> Unary operators are more efficient than standard JavaScript function
> calls

Being as ignorant as I am, I don't quite understand in which way is it more efficient. Are unary operators more performant, or just simply more readable?
[image]

Comment: I think you might want to look for another book. That statement makes very little sense, if any.

Comment: `void` also is definitely not an operator.

Comment: (In fairness, MDN and the spec calls `delete` an operator.)

Comment: Holy ... uhh, holy stack overflow, you're right. Boy that's weird, but ya learn something every day.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void

I believe "void" is identified as an operator according to MDN

Comment: I think they mean unary built-in operators are faster and more efficient because they do not need all the stuff functions have (names, stack trace, other metadata, etc) that could have a drag on performance.

Comment: @GetSet [`void`](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-void-operator) is definitely an operator. What else would it be?

Comment: Efficiency is measured in time complexity. Since these operators have constant time complexity and the time complexity is the same in their function counterparts (if they exist), the efficiency is identical. Operators may be _faster_ (higher _performance_, in ms) than functions, which makes sense, considering that functions rely on function references being looked up and call stacks being maintained. This statement, however, only has value when paired with the statement “Premature optimization is the root of all evil”. If the book doesn’t say _that_, then consider reading a different book.

Comment: @SebastianSimon My understanding changed on the progression of the comments. I was thinking of other languages where `void` can be used to state that a function/method has no return value.